# Oracle Apex Put Page button inside interactive grid next to actions menu

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid but the save button i am using is customized and not the one provided by IG by default.

I want to place it in the actions menu of IG where EDIT, ADD row and others action menu items are present.

OR

If the above is not possible can it be placed within the region title?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to manipulate the row action menu (that is what you're referring to right ?). afaik, that is for row level actions only - not for the entire grid.
The IG save button can be placed anywhere in the IG toolbar - there are plenty of blogs available on how to do that. The button itself cannot be placed elsewhere on the page. However, the IG save button is not the only way to submit an IG. If the page is submitted, the IG will save as well. So you can place a Save button anywhere on the page with action "Submit Page" and that will save the interactive grid.